# iOS : kCCDecodeError -4304

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes

I encrypt a login in php with this script :

```
//PHP Code
    function cypherAES128($plaintext, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);


    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB/*, $iv*/);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    return $ciphertext;
}

function uncypherAES128($ciphertext, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);  

    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB/*, $iv*/);      
    return $plaintext;
}
```

I get the encrypted password in my iOS app, and try to decrypt it with [FBEncryptorAES](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor).

I can get the login decrypted back if it is smaller than 16 character.

```
//PHP Code
echo cypherAES128("aShortLogin", $key);   //this encrypted login can be decrypted
echo cypherAES128("loginGreaterThan16Characters", $key);   //this encrypted login cannot
```

When the encrypted word is greater than 15 char, I got a kCCDecodeError -4304.

A little precision : 
It sounds like long login can be encrypted then decrypted whithin the PHP script, 
AND encrypted then decrypted with FBEncryptor.
Only PHP encrypt => objectiveC decrypt doesn't works

Any idea please?? I'm a beginner in iOS and cryptography.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english.

[EDIT]
Don't sure the problem is only the objectiveC, because as I said, the FBEncryptor can decode text it encoded itself.

The error appears when I excecute this code :

```
//Objective-C code:
NSString * decryptedLogin = [FBEncryptorAES decryptBase64String: encryptedLogin keyString:AESKey];
```

Whith "encryptedLogin" = the value returned by the PHP script.
Changing value and lenght of AESKey doesn't seem to work. (AESKey = same key as the $key in PHP)
Tried 16 & 32 bytes length key.

I don't changed the code in FBEncryptorAES, here is decryptBase64String :

```
//Objective-C code
+ (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv;
{
NSData* result = nil;

// setup key
unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
[key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

// setup iv
char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
if (iv) {
    [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
}

// setup output buffer
size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

// do decrypt
size_t decryptedSize = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                      FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      cKey,
                                      FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                      cIv,
                                      [data bytes],
                                      [data length],
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &decryptedSize);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
} else {
    free(buffer);
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
}

return result;
}
```

The String is converted into a Base64 string. I don't think that the conversion is the problem.

Comment: It might be better to show the iOS code versus the PHP code since the problem is on the client side. In addition, AES is a block cipher, so you need to pass the data in 16-byte chunks.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I edited my post to add more details
How do I pass the data in 16-byte chunks?
If my login is 14AAAAAAAAAAAAAA3BBB, would have I to encrypt first 14AAAAAAAAAAAAAA then 3BBB?

Comment: Problem solved by using MCRYPT_MODE_CBC in my PHP code.
I cannot answer my own question until 5 hours because I'm a newcomer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!!!!

just use "MCRYPT_MODE_CBC" in my php script instead of "MCRYPT_MODE_ECB".

```
//PHP Code: 
  // $key must be 32 bytes
  $key="32-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";


    function cypherAES128($plaintext, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);


    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC/*, $iv*/);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    return $ciphertext;
}

function uncypherAES128($ciphertext, $key)
{
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);  

    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC/*, $iv*/);      
    return $plaintext;
}
```

It seems that there is 5 ways to crypt with AES, and that my iOS code / PHP code didn't used the same.

Thank for your answer, and I hope this will help!